# ActiveRecord cache_key does not change for included tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the query

```
  query = A.all.includes(:bs)

  Rails.cache.fetch(query.cache_key) do
    .....
  end
```

When the content of a record included from the B model changes the cache key is not expired and the old data is fetched. Is there any way to have cache_key check for changes on tables in `includes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the api docs and reading the source for cache_key it seems that table joins in the query are not supported and the cache key only checks for updates on the first model. There does not seem to be a simple fix other than implementing a custom version of cache key that does a similar thing but for multiple tables.